# Password Protection macro won't work

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that will password protect a bunch of excel files at once. I've managed to work out (read "Frankenstein-from-various-sources-and-old-code") the following that should request a file path and a password to use, then cycle through each file in the folder and password protect them. Unfortunately, it requests the path and password but it then immediately ends without password protecting the files. My vba is basically all rust at this point, so I'm unfortunately struggling to work out why it isn't working.

And yes, I know this isn't best practice. Unfortunately I have several hundred documents to password protect, and no time to do this with.

Does anyone have any ideas?

CODE:

```
Sub ProtectAll()
Dim wBk As Workbook
Dim sFileSpec As String
Dim sPathSpec As String
Dim sFoundFile As String
Dim sPassword As String

sPathSpec = InputBox("Path to use", "Path")
sPassword = InputBox("Enter Password Below", "Password")
sFileSpec = "*.xlsx"

sFoundFile = Dir(sPathSpec & sFileSpec)
Do While sFoundFile <> ""
    Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPathSpec & sFoundFile)
    With wBk
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wBk.SaveAs Filename:=.FullName, _
          Password:=sPassword
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    Set wBk = Nothing
    Workbooks(sFoundFile).Close False
    sFoundFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

I'm using path

```
C:\Users\ [MYNAME] \Desktop\Password Test
```

and password

```
TEST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just missing the last `\` in your path, I've added a line to force the inputed path finish with it.

Also, no need to try to close the initial workbook after the `SaveAs` because it'd have changed.

```
Sub ProtectAll()
Dim wBk As Workbook
Dim sFileSpec As String
Dim sPathSpec As String
Dim sFoundFile As String
Dim sPassword As String

sPathSpec = InputBox("Path to use", "Path")
If Right(sPathSpec, 1) <> "\" Then sPathSpec = sPathSpec & "\"
sPassword = InputBox("Enter Password Below", "Password")
sFileSpec = "*.xlsx"

sFoundFile = Dir(sPathSpec & sFileSpec)
Do While sFoundFile <> vbNullString
    Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPathSpec & sFoundFile)
    With wBk
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs filename:=.FullName, Password:=sPassword
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close
    End With
    Set wBk = Nothing
    sFoundFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: ok, so just to confirm the theory - this looks to see if "sPathspec" ends with \ and if not it adds a \?

Comment: @Miller86 : Yup, that's it! ;)

Comment: Legendary. That works! You sir/madam, are a gentleman and a scholar, and I take my hat off to you.

Comment: If an answer works for you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. Also, can madam be a gentleman? ;)

Comment: @Miller86 : If it indeed solved your issue, please accept the answer! ;)

Comment: @user7640152 doesn't a comment always poke the previous commenter?

Comment: I was waiting for the tickmark to become available. Its available now so its accepted. Thanks again :)

Comment: @DavidGlickman : Not sure, post author will always be. But as for previous commenter, it's not clearly said : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting